# Circuitikz custom symbol

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

I want to reproduce the circuit below:

[image]

How can I reproduce the circulator symbol? Circuitikz have some thermodynamic symbols library?

My code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]
        \draw (0,0) to (0,1.5);
        \draw (0,1.5) to (0.5,1.5);
        \draw (0.5,1.5) to [R, l_=$q_{refrigerator}$](1.5,1.5);
        \draw (1.5, 1.5) to (4,1.5);
        \draw (4,1.5) to (4,0);
        \draw (4,0) to [R, l_=$q$](0,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0.25,1.25) rectangle ++(1.5,2);
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (1,2.75) {Refrigerator\\or storage\\reservoir};
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (2,-0.5) {Channels of internally\\cooled device};
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (3,2.75) {Pump or\\compressor};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: this should help -- http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/speaker.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Second version

The approach I used before (you can look at it in the history of the answer) was *wrong*. An explanation at the end.

You can leverage an empty source here, using the standard "decoration" for labels and the arrow --- which resembles a straight voltage. Then you can add the lines to the shape. After naming `P` the shape, you have a set of anchors that you can use. In this case, I used the expression (requires `calc`, but that is loaded by `circuitikz`):

```
($(P.center)!1!60:(P.east)$)
```

that expression means: consider the line from `P.center` to `P.east`, full length (this is the `1`), then rotate it `60` degrees to find the requested coordinate. See [Ti*k*Z manual around page 147, "The Syntax for Partway Modifiers"](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5.3).

I have added comments to the code to explain.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.78mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]
        \draw (0,0) to (0,1.5);
        \draw (0,1.5) to (0.5,1.5);
        % notice also how I have written the symbol here, and compare 
        % the position of the "f"
        \draw (0.5,1.5) to [R, l^=$\dot{q}_{\mathit{refrigerator}}$](1.5,1.5);
        % an empty generator with name "P" and its labels...
        \draw (1.5, 1.5) to[esource, name=P,
            l=$\dot{q}_{\mathit{circulator}}$,
            voltage=straight, v_<=$\dot{m}$,
            ] (4,1.5);
        % let's decorate it. Look at Ti*k*Z manual, page 147
        \draw [thick] ($(P.center)!1!60:(P.east)$) -- ($(P.center)!1!170:(P.east)$);
        \draw [thick] ($(P.center)!1!-60:(P.east)$) -- ($(P.center)!1!-170:(P.east)$);
        \draw (4,1.5) to (4,0);
        \draw (4,0) to [R, l_=$q$](0,0);
        \draw[dashed] (0.25,1.25) rectangle ++(1.5,2);
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (1,2.75) {Refrigerator\\or storage\\reservoir};
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (2,-0.5) {Channels of internally\\cooled device};
        \node[font=\sffamily, align = center] at (3,2.75) {Pump or\\compressor};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum** The old answer used border anchor, which (as written explicitly in the manual) should not be used for this. They are used to position the label, voltages etc., and they track the rectangle around the symbol, not the symbol itself. Things are too tangled to change them in a backward-compatible way, so...